# Redirect URI API Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have a Google Analytics API and want to include in a site where already contains content so already have a index, but index.html, how do i add the api to the site ? which file (oauth2callback.php,index.php) i call on the link that will give access to the API ? Should i state in the client_secrets.json file on redirect_uris the uri that will be redirected ? On the current state of my site, when i click on the link that leads to oauth2callback.php file the site goes to index.html, but i want it to go to index.php

Comment: You have to set Redirect URI in Google API console where Client ID and Secret are available.

Comment: Welcome to stack your question is unclear.  Can you post a small example of what you are trying to accomplish. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve